# Joda: how to generate an ISO datetime string with "Z" at the and

Tags: scala, jodatime

I generate an ISO datetime string (without time zone) like this:

```
val dateTime: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now
val dateTimeStr: String = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).print(dateTime)
```

The code above produces the following string:

```
2014-04-10T06:13:19.283
```

Now I need to convert this string back to a `LocalDateTime`...

```
val dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr, ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC))
```

... and compare it with the current time:

```
val isBefore = dateTime.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now)
```

The code above doesn't work and produces the following error:

```
Invalid format: \"2014-04-27T17:51:06.780\" is too short
```

To fix the problem, I need to append a `Z` to `dateTimeStr`:

```
val dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(s"${dateTimeStr}Z", ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC))
```

Is there a way to generate the ISO datetime string with the `Z` at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `LocalDateTime` has NO timezone. So you cannot associate a timezone-aware format (Z stands for UTC timezone) with this zoneless data type.

If you insist on having Z-formats then you have to work with a global type like `DateTime`. So you have two different steps. One step is object conversion between local and global type:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = ...;
DateTime dt = ldt.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC); // or another timezone

// reverse
DateTime dt = ...;
LocalDateTime ldt = dt.toLocalDateTime();
```

Second step is conversion between formatted string form and global timestamp:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = ...;
DateTime dt = ldt.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC); // or another timezone
String iso = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().print(dt);

// reverse
String iso = ...; // with trailing Z or another timezone information
DateTime dt = IsoDateTimeFormat.parseDateTime(iso);
LocalDateTime ldt = dt.toLocalDateTime();
```

Finally you can combine these two steps for conversion between ISO-format with timezone information and a `LocalDateTime` as shown in the second step.

If you only need formatted strings without any timezone or offset information then you can stick the global type `DateTime` completely and just use [localDateOptionalTimeParser()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#localDateOptionalTimeParser%28%29) as @Sebastian has correctly mentioned.

Comment: As far as I know, LocalDateTime uses UTC internally, isn't it?

Comment: @j3d No, LocalDateTime only contains year, month, dayOfMonth, hourOfDay, minute, second and nanosecond, nothing else. LocalDateTime does not even refer to any timezone or UTC by spec. Just look at the source code. LocalDateTime is a pure combination of LocalDate and LocalTime.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use

```
val dateTime: DateTime = DateTime.now
```

instead of

```
val dateTime: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now
```

Or if you want to stick to `LocalDateTime` change the parsing:

```
val dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr)  // this uses the default localDateOptionalTimeParser
```

Comment: Then consequently use a format which doesn't require a timezone. See my second suggestion.